# Check what DB a JVM is using?

Tags: java

A JVM is running with a pile of code that I didn't do any development. I think I know what JDBC connection it is using from grepping logfiles etc but I am not 100% sure. Is there any tool which can tell you the JDBC connection details that a JVM is using?

Comment: How'd you connect to the database to begin with?  Where are the connection credentials located?  (Hint:  that will tell you what database you're using.)

Comment: My hunch is the OP does not know how the connection was established because he has the "luck" to check on a machine the operator of which has gone missing. Insofar I think the question does not deserve to be downvoted. I would got with `lsof` or `netstat` to start with the network connection.

Comment: @Makoto  question updated